# Activiti Api methods

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

**1, get all task assigned to a user**

```
// its working.
 List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee(userId).list()
```

**2, get all task assigned to groups**

```
//tasks list empty, its not working
 List<Task> tasks =  taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroupIn(roles).list()
```

**3, clam a task**

```
//its working
 taskService.claim(taskId, userId)
```

**4, revoke a task**

```
// i don't know this is the right way
 taskService.claim(taskId,null)
```

**5, start process instance**

```
//its working
 ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(pdId, variables);
```

**6, complete a task**

```
//its working
 taskService.complete(taskId,variables)
```

**7, get from properties for a task**

```
// its working

 List<FormProperty> formList = formService.getTaskFormData(taskId).getFormProperties();
```

I want to make sure that i am doing in right way.. please correct if i am wrong

**Update for answer**

**7) get from properties for a task**

I have to loop through formList and using getId() and getValue() i got what i want

**2) get all task assigned to groups**

taskCandidateGroupIn(roles) // here roles must be List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormProperty is an object that holds the information about the specific form property. If you look at the [documentation](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#formProperties), you will see how it is implemented.

Comment: @Xargos.. Thanks anyway.. i got that